# Debug Log messages not appearing before execution of big chunk of code, only after this is finished, using Update()

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

Whenever using the Update() method as follows:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && useRandomSeed) {
        Debug.Log("Generating New Map...");
        GenerateMap();
        Debug.Log("New Map Generated!");
    }
}
```

The Output of the console will push out the first message and second message (visually) simultaneously. while `GenerateMap()` is executed first.
`GenerateMap()` is a method that takes a while before it returns.

*What was expected:*

- First debug message is printed.
- Code is executed.
- Second debug message is printed.

*What happened:*

- Code is executed.
- First and second debug messages are printed (in order).

I tried doing this:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && useRandomSeed && !mapGenPending) {
        Debug.Log("Generating New Map...");
        mapGenPending = true;
    } else if (mapGenPending) {
        GenerateMap();
        Debug.Log("New Map Generated!");
        mapGenPending = false;
    }
}
```

But this still resulted in the second case. I thought Unity might not care about the order of certain pieces of code within the `Update()` per cycle, but even 2 cycles is not enough for the message to be printed in console in order.

**Ultimately, how does one prevent this from happening, to get the order as expected?**

Comment: This seems weird. I have never faced this. Could you also add the output you get in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a coroutine for procedures, for example:

```
public IEnumerator LoadMap(){
        Debug.Log("Generating New Map...");
        GenerateMap();            
        while(generated==false){
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
        Debug.Log("New Map Generated!");
}
```

On Update:

```
void Update(){
       if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
              StartCoroutine(LoadMap());
       }
}
```

On your Class:

```
private bool generated = false;
```

On your GenerateMap Method:

```
public void GenerateMap(){
//
//
//
//
     generated=true;
}
```

This way, the  `New Map Generated!` Message, will appear when generated change from false to true.

Comment: This did not work, for some reason the first debug message only appears whenever the map is done generating. so any debug log messages happening within and outside the coroutine will output at (roughly) the same time, instead of One before the process, and one after the process.

Comment: Can you update the code with the coroutine in it?, I think that you misunderstand somenthing.